# "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" in react npm run dev using vite

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vite

Bit new to React, when I add the following I am getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" and unable to build any new changes in any .jsx file.

- How to fix this issue?
- How to clean and build all the files using - npm run dev ?

...

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REAT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: "myfirebase-b9b85.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "myfirebase-b9b85",
  storageBucket: "myfirebase-b9b85.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "560026434416",
  appId: "1:5600234416:web:5991f68aeb4540aeadb5"
};


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
```

...

I try to include the following in my App.jsx, still I am not able to get rid of the issue.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

function App() {

  dotenv.config();
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

`apiKey: import.meta.env.REAT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had same issue but when I add VITE_ in front of the variable, it worked perfectly.             apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_REAT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY